# TextView changes size because of margin

Tags: android, xml, view

When I use Android:margin to position textView half-outside it's parent, it acts weirdly: changes it's own size and text is moving inside textView box. How do I prevent it?
On image: left textView has cropped text at the end, and I don't want that.

[image]

```
<FrameLayout
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:layout_margin="16dp"
    android:clipChildren="false">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:ellipsize="none"
        android:singleLine="true"
        android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
        android:textSize="22.5dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="200dp"
        tools:text="0 TEXT VIEWVIEW"
        tools:textColor="#000000" />
<...>
</FrameLayout>
```

Comment: Why are you trying to keep your `TextView` half outside your parent? What's your requirement ?

Comment: I am trying to implement semi-pageViewer (for textViewes, for now), with half-showing neighbor pages.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have two problems here:

1. You are using a `FrameLayout`. This means that when you keep increasing the margin of child, the view is gonna move out of the parent. Why? Because that's how `FrameLayout` is designed. Read documentation here: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/FrameLayout.html

> FrameLayout is designed to block out an area on the screen to display a single item. Generally, FrameLayout should be used to hold a single child view, because it can be difficult to organize child views in a way that's scalable to different screen sizes without the children overlapping each other.

So instead you could use `RelativeLayout` or `LinearLayout`.

2. The second problem you have is `android:singleLine="true"`. This means that as the text increases in length, it will still be shown in a single line and hence the text will be clipped. So set this to `false`, or just remove this attribute.

   `android:singleLine="false"`

Comment: Thanks! RelativeLayout should work (:
Shouldn't `android:layout_width="wrap_content"` be enough to tell textView to stretch? I really need text to be shown as single line.

Comment: `wrap_content` can stretch, but for how long? Let's say your font size it 20sp, this means that there is a physical limitation on how many characters you can show on a single line maintaining this font size. So as the text size increases, the `TextView` also increases in size, until it reaches the edge of the screen. Then either you need to go ahead with another line, or use ellipsize or let the text get clipped.

Answer (score 2):

`FrameLayout` always overlaps its Children. For effective placing widgets I suggest to use,

`LinearLayout` with `layout_weight`

arrange widgets relative to another widget by using `RelativeLayout`

Answer (score 1):

i think you need to change the line:

```
android:singleLine="true"
```

to false.